# Can I encrypt a purely in-memory database using SQLCipher?

Tags: encryption, sqlite, sqlcipher

The official SQLite Encryption Extension does not support encrypting in-memory databases per their documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki

> ### Limitations
>
> 1. TEMP tables are not encrypted.
> 2. In-memory (":memory:") databases are not encrypted.
> 3. Bytes 16 through 23 of the database file contain header
>        information which is not encrypted.

Does SQLCipher have these same limitations?